# Parallel Processing in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, parallel-processing, cron

I get a file from the user. Once the file has been uploaded and saved, Now this file has to be analysed.
Since it is a huge file and analysis takes minimum 1 hour (say), I have a field in the model saying the status of the analysis as Analysing or Analysis Done.

The script for analysing is a separate python file and the analysis has to be done there.

How do I go about doing this? I want this script to run at the background. Also I have
to deploy in apache server.

How should I proceed?

1. Should I use threads? How do I go about using
   external python scripts in threads?
2. I came to know about CronTabs, But I don't know
   how can I implement in this situation.
3. I can't use Celery, since Celery has been stopped for
   Windows
4. I came to know about Django Management
   Commands. But since I deploy using an Apache
   server, I don't know whether I can do that.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Sorry I am new to django So the thing is, how do I use crontab here? I just have to analyse the file using a script, say a function in external python. But cron seems to be like a scheduler kind of thing which calls the function once in a while. And also does it work when deoplyed on Apache server?

Comment: Celery dropped support for windows in v4, so stick to version 3 and install this app for scheduling; https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat (you just can't use cron on windows)

Comment: I am not advised to use version 3 of Celery, by my professor managing this project.She doesn't want something that's of old version as well. Thats where my problem comes.

Comment: In that case I'd argue that you need a linux server to do this. There's nothing wrong with using celery 3 if it provides the functionality you need.

Comment: Aahh! Ok What do you think of Threads ?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to solve this problem.

If you can batch the processing of the files, then you can run a cron job which will run a django command or a script at certain intervals to process the file.

If you can't batch the processing, you should look at other queuing systems like [django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq) or you can build a simple queuing system using an event dispatch library.

If you really want to use celery what you can do is run your whole project inside a docker container so that you can use celery 4 since that is your requirement.